# header not appearing correctly after using margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I wanted to use in particle.js in the header and write a few things over the header but the header just goes below the particles-js background.. I will attach a photo and then you can see what I mean..
doesn't matter  if the margin-top is 0vh or 50vh, it still goes down..

[image]

this is the html section..

```css
#particles-js {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #3bade3 0%, #576fe6 25%, #9844b7 51%, #ff357f 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #3bade3 0%, #576fe6 25%, #9844b7 51%, #ff357f 100%);
}


}
#head1 {
  margin: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 40px 0px;
}
.header-content {
  margin-top: 0vh;
}
.header-title,
.header-sub-title {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333;
}
.header-title {
  font-size: 112px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 1;
}
.header-sub-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="head1">
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <div class="header-content">
    <h1 class="header-title">BEST Plan</h1>
    <p class="header-sub-title">ggjfkfk</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /.header-content -->
</section>
```

i did add the particle.js and app.js file

Answer (score 0):

It's not simply a question of margin, because margin is assigned based to the position of the node, which unless is set to `absolute` or similar will not be position relative to the whole body. Add the following style to your title :

```
.header-title {
    font-size: 112px;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px; /* play with the value until it looks right */
}
```

Comment: it only moved the best plan text portion

Comment: Then rename the class to `header-content`.

Comment: thank you, it actually worked. btw there was one more query.. the particle js header becomes very small in mible..should i increase the height of particles using media query or how am i to increase it a bit in mobile view

Comment: Your best bet is the media query.